# Can EF.Property in EF Core work with related object properties

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am building a dynamic filter function using the build in Ef Core EF.Property function.

```
 private static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string filterValue)
 {
     return source.Where(c =>
            EF.Functions.Like(EF.Property<string>(c, propertyName).ToLower(), $"{filterValue}%".ToLower()));
 }
```

It works fine with simple properties like Name and Age, but if used on a object property like Customer.CompanyName then it fails.

An example of a none dynamic query with a filter on Customer.CompanyName

```
query = query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Customer.CompanyName.ToLower(), ""));
```

Are there a workaround?

Comment: `if used on a object property ` That's a related entity, not a property. Or rather, a property on a related entity. You're trying to use the method on the wrong object. Apart from that, LINQ is dynamic already and what you posted has at least one killer bug - that `ToLower()` will prevent the server from using indexes *and* probably return the wrong results. Equality  (and indexing) is controlled by the columns collation with most databases using a case *in*-sensitive collation. Calling `ToLower()` will emit function calls that prevent the database from using indexes that cover that column

Comment: Besides, if the database designer/developer wanted the column to be case *sensitive*, they had a reason. `ToLower()` will result in a query that "magically" ignores the explicit collation and returns unexpected results, with no apparent cause. After all, the database remains case sensitive, the developer's query does *not* call `ToLower()` so who changed the collation?

Comment: The search has to be case insensitive. or it would not be very user friendly. So the DBA a aware of it

Comment: How am I using it on the wrong object? how should I then access it?

Comment: When you use `Employee.Name` you're accessing the `Name` property of the `Employee` entity. When you use `Employee.Company.CompanyName` you're trying to access the `CompanyName` of a `Company` entity related to `Employee`. This *expression* isn't the name of a property, it's the path to a related entity's property. You'd have to parse that string, extract the actual property name `Company`, access that entity and then access its `CompanyName` property

Comment: Once again though, why? If there's an actual reason, don't try to do it from scratch. Use [LINQkit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) as a starting point

Comment: You could also check the non-Microsoft [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq/) package and its [source](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, then `EF.Property` is not a good option.
The following code contains some Expression Tree "magic" but I hope it will be helpful in creating other extensions.

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string filterValue)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
    var body = (Expression) param;
    foreach (var propName in propertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, propName);
    }

    body = Expression.Call(body, "ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
    body = Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions), "Like", Type.EmptyTypes,
        Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), body, Expression.Constant($"{filterValue}%".ToLower()));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, param);

    var queryExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new[] {typeof(T)}, source.Expression, lambda);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(queryExpr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I will try the code

Comment: You are awesome (-: Your code just works and now I just have to learn about expression trees. Thanks again have been working on that problem for days

Comment: @MartinAndersen. If you want I can post more easier implementation, but it needs additional `ReplacingVisitor` class.

Comment: I think the code is very clear and readable. I just need to learn more about expressions trees

Comment: Yes, but it is boring do such complex manipulations and there is more intuitive way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, more sophisticated but powerful. Idea is to result C# compiler's possibility to create Expression Tree and just correct them at the end.

Usage is simple but reusable:

```cs
string filterValue = "A";
query = query.FilterByPattern("Customer.CompanyName",
    (string v) => EF.Functions.Like(v.ToLower(), $"{filterValue}%"));
```

The same filter function as described in question written using this extension

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propPath, string filterValue)
{
    return query.FilterByPattern(propPath, 
      (string v) => EF.Functions.Like(v.ToLower(), $"{filterValue}%"));
}
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterByPattern<T, TProp>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propPath,
        Expression<Func<TProp, bool>> predicatePattern)
    {
        return query.Where(MakePredicate<T, TProp>(propPath, predicatePattern));
    }

    public static Expression GetPath(Expression obj, string propPath)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propPath))
        {
            foreach (var propName in propPath.Split('.'))
            {
                obj = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, propName);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> MakePredicate<T, TProp>(string propPath,
        Expression<Func<TProp, bool>> predicatePattern)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var body = GetPath(param, propPath);

        body = ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(predicatePattern, body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    }

    class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly IDictionary<Expression, Expression> _replaceMap;

        public ExpressionReplacer(IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            _replaceMap = replaceMap ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaceMap));
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression exp)
        {
            if (exp != null && _replaceMap.TryGetValue(exp, out var replacement))
                return replacement;
            return base.Visit(exp);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, Expression toReplace, Expression toExpr)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> {{toReplace, toExpr}}).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(replaceMap).Visit(expr);
        }
        
        public static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression lambda, params Expression[] toReplace)
        {
            if (lambda.Parameters.Count != toReplace.Length)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return new ExpressionReplacer(lambda.Parameters.Zip(toReplace)
                .ToDictionary(e => (Expression)e.First, e => e.Second)).Visit(lambda.Body);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is more type-safe, because you pass parameters as lambda expressions. It is based on Svyatoslav Danyliv's one.

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereLike<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, string? search, Expression<Func<TEntity, string?>> propertySelector)
    where TEntity : class
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        return query;
    }

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "p");
    var property = Expression.Invoke(propertySelector, parameter);
    
    var likeMethod = typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like), [typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string), typeof(string)]);
    var likeExpression = Expression.Call(null, likeMethod!, Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), property, Expression.Constant($"%{search}%"));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(likeExpression, parameter);

    var queryExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),  nameof(Queryable.Where), [typeof(TEntity)], query.Expression, lambda);

    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(queryExpression);
}
```